# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo throwing InvalidOperationExpcetion

Tags: sql-server, exception, sqlconnection, smo

I am using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` to read database schema in a web API 2.0 application and validating asynchronous AJAX requests from the client.

I often encounter the exception

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

while I access the schema to do the validation of tables, views, stored procedures and table functions and finally grab the connection string, create a separate `SqlConnection` and command to execute the caller's query.

it seems that the database objects are loaded on demand and a data reader is being left open and my new `SqlConnection` is getting a pooled connection that's not been properly closed.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and if so, how did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well when I ran multiple threads against a shared Smo.Server object.

I resolved the issue by creating new instances of the Smo.Server object for every thread that accessed the data in Smo.

Be aware that this may have performance implications if you continually instantiate new Smo.Server objects.  If that is the case, it may be beneficial to share the Smo.Server object and carefully use [lock objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to prevent simultaneous access.